# Object found but document properties undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working on a programming example with Meteor and Javascript and I'm facing a strange problem. This is my code:

```
Items.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return (userId && doc.owner === userId);
  },
  update: function(userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
    console.log("------------");
    console.log(docs);
    return _.all(docs, function(doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      console.log(doc.name);
      console.log(doc._id);
      console.log(doc.owner);
      console.log(userId);
      return doc.owner === userId;
    });
  }
});
```

When I try to update one object of the Items collection using the Javascript console

```
Items.update({_id: "cY87rAW8g4f92bRY2"}, {$set: {price: "$20"}});
```

I see the following in the console:

```
------------
{ name: 'two',
  owner: 'ZGXiBDBR6J5XdTHSe',
  _id: 'cY87rAW8g4f92bRY2' }
two
undefined
undefined
undefined
ZGXiBDBR6J5XdTHSe
```

The first log in the console "console.log(doc);" shows that I'm updating the right item but the rest of the console logs doc.name, doc._id and doc.owner are undefined. This in effect causes that the update fails because I cannot compare doc.owner with the userId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `_.all` iterates over an array or object, and update is passed a **single** doc, `_.all` iterates over the properties of that document.

So when `two` was output, that was a result of the `console.log(doc)` line. The undefined outputs are you trying to log the properties of a property itself.

Hence, remove the `_.all` wrapper to the block and you'll be fine:

```
update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
  console.log(doc);
  console.log(doc.name);
  console.log(doc._id);
  console.log(doc.owner);
  console.log(userId);
  return doc.owner === userId;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right, untrusted code (e.g. client-side code such as event handlers and a browser's JavaScript console) can only modify a single document at once, specified by its _id. The modification is allowed only after checking any applicable allow and deny rules. My code could work from on the server side but not on the client.

Comment: @Alberto you still have to use a loop on the server to modify multiple documents or use a bulk modifying selector. Node's mongodb driver added batch inserts slightly later to the other mongodb node native functions & its not yet implemented in meteor

Answer (score 1):

What does the `_.all` do? It looks like its setting `name` as the root element of `doc`, which doesn't have any keys so it returns undefined. Your code should work fine without it:

```
update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    console.log(doc);
    console.log(doc.name);
    console.log(doc._id);
    console.log(doc.owner);
    console.log(userId);
    return doc.owner === userId;
}
```

I changed `docs` to `doc` too because in collection.allow, [update handles a single document](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow), not an array of them, each update will individually be run against allow/deny

Comment: Your proposed code works regarding the access to the properties .name, ._id and .owner. The ._all allows to iterate through all the documents being updated e.g. Items.update({_id: "cY87rAW8g4f92bRY2"}, {$set: {price: "$20"}}, {_id: "DEDdTMgdvpmGDFF5b"}, {$set: {price: "$30"}});

Comment: I'm not entirely sure meteor can do batch updates at the moment, you have to put each in a loop

Comment: Meteor explicitly disallows batch updates on the client as of [0.5.8](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/03/13/meteor-058-security-fix-appcache-db-transforms-new-deps)

Comment: @Swadq batch updates/inserts were never supported in Meteor in the form Alberto wants to use on both the client and server. I think you meant using arbitrary selectors have been depreciated from 0.5.8 which disallows more than one document being updated with a single selector on the client

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I meant - I was unsure how the `allow` rules used to work before 0.5.8, so I assumed that it split any updates into an array of individual documents, hence Alberto's confusion - obviously not!